# Can you use dictionary with the generalnn category in MS Text API?

Tags: microsoft-translator, neural-mt

Is there a way to upload a terminology dictionary to the Hub, that would be applied when translating using generalnn category (not a trained engine)?

The workaround that seem to work is to use the <mstrans:dictionary> tag e.g.:

```
Let's do a <mstrans:dictionary translation="tłumaczenie">translation</mstrans:dictionary>!
```

But this require to (1) preprocess each sample before sending for translation, and (2) wont work when you're targetting multiple languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the permanent dictionary functionality is not there yet for neural systems. The markup as you describe is the only current workaround.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it means that it limits the multiple languages functionality: If I have a text `This text` and I know/force the `text` translation in language A and B, I cannot submit one request `target language = A+B` but one request with language A for translation in A and the same for B. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for the confirming it Chris. Is this still applicable with the new Custom Translator (http://portal.customtranslator.azure.ai/) - I didn't yet have a time to play around with it.